# Getting a path of a file. C#

Tags: c#

I want the Filewatcher to watch the path of the FileBrowseBox, but with the FileBrowseBox you have to choose a file. How do i watch the path the file is in? So I need to FileWatch the input of the FileBrowseBox. I have no idea how. I got a code and a printscreen for you guys.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool pause = false;
    private bool cut1 = false;
    private bool copy1 = false;
    Form2 popup = new Form2();


    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    // The lines with performed actions of a file
    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Changed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Deleted> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Changed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Deleted> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher2_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File Renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    //1st directory
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;  // Stop watching
            fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fileSystemWatcher1.Path = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
            textBox1.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;         // Text of textBox2 = Path of fileSystemWatcher2
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;   // Begin watching
        }
    }
    //2nd directory
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileSystemWatcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = false;  // Stop watching
            fileSystemWatcher2.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fileSystemWatcher2.Path = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
            textBox2.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;         // Text of textBox2 = Path of fileSystemWatcher2
            fileSystemWatcher2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;   // Begin watching
        }
    }
    //log
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DialogResult resDialog = dlgSaveFile.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dlgSaveFile.FileName);
            StreamWriter sw = fi.CreateText();
            foreach (string sItem in listBox1.Items)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(sItem);
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    //pause watching
    private void pause_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            pause = true;
            pause_button.Text = "Unpause";
        }
        else
        {
            pause = false;
            pause_button.Text = "Pause Watching";
        }
    }
    //clear listbox
    private void clear_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear(); 
    }

    private void Transfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //copy a file
        if (copy1)
        {
            DialogResult dialogresult = popup.ShowDialog();
            var source = FileBrowseBox.Text;
            var target = Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(source)));

            if (File.Exists(target))
            {

                if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    File.Delete(target);
                }
                else if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(FileBrowseBox.Text, Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(FileBrowseBox.Text))));
            }
            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(FileBrowseBox.Text, Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(FileBrowseBox.Text))));
            }
        }
        //cut a file
        if (cut1)
        {
            DialogResult dialogresult = popup.ShowDialog();
            var source = FileBrowseBox.Text;
            var target = Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(source)));

            if (File.Exists(target))
            {

                if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    File.Delete(target);
                }
                else if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                File.Move(FileBrowseBox.Text, Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(FileBrowseBox.Text))));
            }
            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                File.Move(FileBrowseBox.Text, Path.Combine(DestinationBox.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(FileNameBox.Text, Path.GetExtension(FileBrowseBox.Text))));
            }
        }
    }
    private void Browse_file_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult resDialog = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileBrowseBox.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void Browse_destination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult resDialog = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            DestinationBox.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void CopyButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        copy1 = true;
    }

    private void Cut_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cut1 = true;
    }
}
}
```

[image: My application]

i do need the file for transferring but i also need the path it is in. How do i put the path of the file in FilebrowseBox in FileSystemWatcher1?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're looking for, but perhaps you want a folder browser instead of a file browser?

Comment: use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx

Comment: @DanPuzey i do need the file for transferring but i also need the path it is in. How do i put the path of the file in FilebrowseBox in FileSystemWatcher1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example that should fix it the string filepath in the example should be one of your textboxes

```
string filePath = @"C:\MyDir\MySubDir\myfile.ext";
string directoryName;
int i = 0;

while (filePath != null)
{
directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
Console.WriteLine("GetDirectoryName('{0}') returns '{1}'",
    filePath, directoryName);
filePath = directoryName;
if (i == 1)
{
    filePath = directoryName + @"\";  // this will preserve the previous path
}
i++;
}
```